# The book of which the price is high is informative. (do we need 'the' in 'the price'?)

Tags: definite-article

> The book of which **the** price is high is informative.

> The book of which price is high is informative.

I think we need 'the' beause it is modified by of which.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these are correct. "of which" doesn't make sense there. You could perhaps say:

> The book whose price is high ...

But I presume you're comparing books, and want to say that the one with the higher price is more useful. So say that:

> The higher-priced book is more informative.

Comment: or "more expensive book".  (I'd also remove the more before "informative", it's not there in the OP's sentence)

Comment: I think both of them are right if next example is right: Look at the book of which the cover is red. Look at the book the cover of which is red. Look at the book whose cover is red.

Comment: My mistake, first one is right and second is wrong because we need "the"